# How do I render a detail view in Pug instead of all its objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, sequelize.js

I'm building an app using Express, Node, and Pug. In Express, I have an endpoint for `GET books/:id`. I'm grabbing all of the books in the middleware function, and then I render the view. In the view, I loop over all the books, and instead of displaying only one book detail I display all of the books. How do I only render the detail view for one book?

Here's the detail page endpoint:

```
// GET the book detail page
router.get('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
bookQuery = Book.findAll({
    include: [
        { model: Loan }
    ],
    order: [["title", "DESC"]]
}).then((books) => {
    console.log(books);
    res.render('book_detail', {
        books: books,
        // title: loans.Book.title,
        // author: loans.Book.author,
        // genre: loans.Book.genre,
        // first_published: loans.Book.first_published,
        // patronFirstName: loans.Patron.first_name,
        // patronLastName: loans.Patron.last_name,
        // loanedOn: loans.loaned_on,
        // return_by: loans.return_by,
        // returned_on: loans.returned_on

    });
});
});
```

Here's the view:

```
extends ./layout
block content
    body
        each book in books
            h1 Book: #{book.title}
            form
                p
                    label(for='title') Title
                    input#title(type='text', value=book.title)
                p
                    label(for='author') Author
                    input#author(type='text', value=book.author)
                p
                    label(for='genre') Genre
                    input#genre(type='text', value=book.genre)
                p
                    label(for='first_published') First Published
                    input#first_published(type='text', 
value=book.first_published)
                p
                    input(type='submit', value='Update')
            h2 Loan History
            table
                thead
                    tr
                        th Book
                        th Patron 
                        th Loaned on
                        th Return by 
                        th Returned on
                        th Action
                tbody
                    tr
                        td
                            a(href=`/books/book_detail`)= book.title
                        td
                            //- a(href=`/patrons/patron_detail`)=book.Loan.first_name + ' ' + book.Loan.last_name
                        if book.Loan
                            a(href='patron_detail.html')
                            td= book.Loan.loaned_on
                            td= book.Loan.return_by
                            td= book.Loan.returned_on
                            td
                                a.button(href='return_book.html') Return Book
```

Comment: Why are you grabbing _all_ of the books in the first place? Is there a reason you aren't grabbing just the one book by its `id`?

Comment: I agree with @AndrewMyers but if you are going to go forward with the 'get all books and only render one' you may need to match on the ID with a pug conditional, documented here: https://pugjs.org/language/conditionals.html

Comment: @AndrewMyers I'm using Sequelize ORM for this project, and so far as I know I have to query for all the books in that function, but I could be wrong. Can't I just somehow redirect the user to the book detail for the selected book? But how would my view know that?

Comment: @GregSyme How would I grab the selected id and use that in the conditional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Pug. Pug just renders the data.

The problem is that you are using `Book.findAll()`. This gets an array of books. You should use [`Book.findOne()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findOne) to get a **single** book. You also need to specify `where: { id: req.params.id }` to find the one book that has the id supplied in the URL.

You'd also probably want to change the variable `books` to `book`. And the line `each book in books` in the view would be unnecessary.

The [Model Usage section of the manual](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html) has a lot of examples of querying. I find it easier to read through than the API reference I linked to above.